# JTable Design Guide in Swing Application

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a really hard design problem in my swing application.  Generally Speaking, I have a `JTable` and a `JLabel` to display.  The label is right below the table.

- When the height of these two components doesn't exceed a ***threshold***, then the table and label displays as normal. Then height of these two components will increase as the number of records filled in the table increases.
- When the height of these two components exceeds a threshold, I want there is a scroll bar in the table and the height of these two components will be the threshold.

Is this design ***Possible***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing layout don't automatically re-layout when a preferred size changes, you'll have to call revalidate (best probably with a TableModelListener which checks if the row count has changed). You also need a layout which sizes the component according to its preferred size, BorderLayout does that for the component in the borders (but not for the one in the center. For a different manager you'll need GridBag or better Mig-/Form- or Table (third party) Layout

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTableLayout {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

                final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 1);
                JTable table = new JTable(model) {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
// view port size should be the same as the preferred size
// limited to the height threshold
                        Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
                        size.height = Math.min(size.height, 100);
                        return size;
                    }
                };

                new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        model.addRow(new Object[] { "Extra row!" });
// trigger a relayout of the panel
                        panel.revalidate();
                        panel.repaint();
                    }
                }).start();

                panel.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

                JLabel label = new JLabel("my label");
                label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
                panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible. Put your `JTable` in a `JScrollPane` where you set the preferred size of the scroll pane.

And use a `LayoutManager` which allows to put those 2 components underneath each other (e.g. a `BorderLayout`). So in pseudo-code

```
JPanel container = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );

JTable table=...;
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane( table );
scroll.setPreferredSize( xxx, xxx );
container.add( scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER );

container.add( new JLabel( "my label" ), BorderLayout.SOUTH );
```

If needed, you can adjust the scroll bar policy of the scroll pane

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. But I couldn't use sroll.setPreferredSize(XXX,XXX) method because If I use this method when then JTable size it not large enough then the label will not right below the JTable, that is, there are some blank space between JTable and my label.